# Unable to get correct output in python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I just started programming and I am learning Python using A Byte of Python. I am having a problem with the modules chapter. I don't really understand modules very well, so maybe this is a dumb question, but I copied and pasted the input and it returned a different output. The input that he suggests is

```
import sys

print('The command line arguments are:')
for i in sys.argv:
    print i

print '\n\nThe PYTHONPATH is', sys.path, '\n'
```

and this is the output:

```
$ python module_using_sys.py we are arguments
The command line arguments are:
module_using_sys.py
we
are
arguments


The PYTHONPATH is ['/tmp/py',
# many entries here, not shown here
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

However my output using the same input is different. Here it is:

```
pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/python$ python modulo1.py
The command line arguments are:
modulo1.py

The PYTHONPATH is ['/home/pedro/Desktop/python', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

I understand that when you write import sys you are making the built in module that as things related to the system available for use. I also know that the for looping statement iterates over a sequence, and the sequence in this case should be the command line arguments that exist. However, it just appears modulo1.py, which is the name of the file where i saved the code i copied and pasted. I don't really understand the pythonpath thing, but according to my research it is the list of directories where potentially exist modules. I use gedit as text editor and ubuntu as os and ubuntu's terminal. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without proper indentation. Can you fix that for us? Use four spaces to signify a code block

Comment: You don't pass any command line args  when you run `modulo1.py`

Comment: I've attempting to format your code. Please take a look and ensure indention is correct

Comment: OP: I don't understand what is wrong. You didn't seem to run `modulo1.py` with any command line arguments, so why would any show up? More to the point: what did you expect your output to be?

Comment: You are also running the code in two different places, where did you run the first .py from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I believe the first code block is the example code from OP's tutorial

Comment: Ignore the PYTHONPATH for now - one version of the script is being run on Mac OS X, the other on Linux - the contents of PYTHONPATH will be vastly different. Instead note that the name of the Python module (`module_using_sys.py` vs `modulo1.py`) is different, and so are the arguments: `we are arguments` vs. no arguments.

Comment: @AdamSmith, then I am totally lost as the code is doing exactly what it should then.

Comment: Ok, the indentation is correct. Sorry for being a bad wanna be programmer, but I don't know why it appears we are arguments in the book's output. Again, this is likely a very stupid thing to ask, but I don't understand what happened.

Comment: To make it clearer... the book is running `$ python module_using_sys.py we are arguments` but you are only running `$ python module_using_sys.py`.

Comment: Also, note that `$ python module_using_sys.py we are arguments` is part of the **input**, specifically the command line the script is being run with. So you need to run yours the same way if you expect the same output.

Comment: So how do I make it the same?

Comment: @pedromatias Try this: `pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/python$ python modulo1.py we are arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement.

`sys.argv` is the list of command line arguments passed to a Python script (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

When you run `$ python modulo1.py`, `modulo1.py` is your first (and only) argument. That's why the output is `modulo1.py`.
But in your book, it runs `$python module_using_sys.py we are arguments`, here `python` is the commend to invoke python. `module_using_sys.py` is the first argument passed to your computer, `we` is the 2nd, `are` is the 3rd, and `arguments` is the last argument.

What the `for` loop do is to print each of these arguments.

So if you would like to see exactly the same output as in your book, you should:

- rename your `.py` file to the same name as in your book
- pass the same arguments to your console

The second statement.

Note that the value of your `sys.path` is different from the value of `sys.path` in the book that you are referring to. This is why you see different output.

Your understanding about `PYTHONPATH` is generally correct. For more information about `PYTHONPATH`, you can check this answer: [How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath) or [this official page](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: So, how do you add the arguments we are arguments

Comment: when you run python by typing `python whatever-appears-here`, the later part `whatever-appears-here` is your argument list. I just edited my answer to include more details. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. (I feel so stupid right now)

Comment: Take your time. Starting is difficult. Things will be better.