# ImportError: No module named app

Tags: python, flask, python-import, flask-testing

I working with Flask-Testing and make file test_app.py to test But I got this error File "test_app.py", line 4, in  from app import create_app, db ImportError: No module named app.
so please help how can I fix it and what is the problem Thanx :)

here is my Structure:

```
myapplication
 app
    __ init __.py
    model.py
    form.py
    autho
    layout
    static
    templates
 migrations  
 test
   -test_app.py
 config.py
 manage.py
```

> test_app.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
import unittest
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from app import create_app, db
from app.model import Users
from flask import request, url_for
import flask

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        return self.app
```

> config.py

```
class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('TEST_DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'mytest.sqlite')
```

> __ init __.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
import psycopg2
from config import basedir
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()
lm = LoginManager()
lm.login_view = 'login'
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'layout.login'

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    # login_manager.user_loader(load_user)
    from .layout import layout as appr_blueprint
    # register our blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(appr_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    return app
```

Comment: You might need to add your `myapplication/` directory to the `$PYTHONPATH` (see http://users-cs.au.dk/chili/PBI/pythonpath.html )

Comment: thnx for ur comment but im not expert in python so should I command (venv)peg@peg:~/myapplication/test$ export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/users/[your username]/myapplication/test/ ??? @BorrajaX

Comment: Almost. Try: `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/users/[your username]/myapplication/` Your `app` module  (or directory) is under `/myapplication/`. Let us know what happens

Comment: I mean... Just to be clear... The path to add to the `$PYTHONPATH` is the full path to the `myapplication` directory. Let's say it's under `/home/borrajax/Documents/Python/myapplication/`, then you'd do `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/borrajax/Documents/Python/myapplication/` (this probably varies for machines with Windows, though)

Comment: Wait... There's a whitespace between the two underscores and `init` in `__ init.py __' and another one between `init.py` and the two final underscores. Is that a type or is it that like that in your computer? 'Cuz it shouldn't have whitespaces `__ init.py __` is not correct. `__init.py__` is.

Comment: it works @BorrajaX :)))) make it as an answer and Thanks

Comment: export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/peg/myapplication/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the comments:

There could have been two issues:

1. The path to `myapplication/` hadn't been added to the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable (more info [here](http://users-cs.au.dk/chili/PBI/pythonpath.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath))
   Let's say the code lives under `/home/peg/myapplication/`. You need to type in your terminal 
   `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/peg/myapplication/`
2. `__init__.py` could have had a typo. There shouldn't be whitespaces between the underscores __ and the *init.py* chunk (`__init__.py` is good, `__ init __.py` is not)

Comment: I have the same exact error, but this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you this solution worked for me. Was deploying a python script on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu.