# Having some trouble using python2 and python3 versions of anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I've got anaconda 3 installed and working, but I need to use python 2.

I've installed anaconda2, but when I launch "python2" from the command line none of the modules can be accessed.

So basically, how do I configure my terminal so that I can access the anaconda modules when I launch python2

Answer (score 0):

Within anaconda, you can install whatever version of python you want through [anaconda virtual environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).
Try the following.

```
conda create -n my_env python=2
source activate my_env
python --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreter looks for its modules based upon settings in PYTHONPATH. See the answer to [How to use Python PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath).

I use Anaconda virtual environments to ease the pain differing version configurations. Read [Managing Environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) for details.