# ImportError: No module named boto.ec2.autoscale

Tags: python, boto

I attempted to run the following [boto library](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autoscale_tut.html#) example:

```
$echo $PYTHONPATH
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

$python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
>>> from boto.ec2.autoscale import AutoScaleConnection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boto.ec2.autoscale

$ls $PYTHONPATH | grep -i boto
boto3
boto3-1.3.0.dist-info
botocore
botocore-1.4.6.dist-info
```

Following this useful [PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19917565/409976) question, I don't understand why that module isn't found.

Comment: Maybe it is `boto3`?

Comment: Thanks. `from boto3.ec2.autoscale import AutoScaleConnection` resulted in `ImportError: No module named autoscale`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you installed [`boto3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto3) instead of [`boto`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto).

Install `boto` or use [`boto3` api](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).