# Python files to class

Tags: python, class, oop

Would I be able to convert these files:

```
### one.py ###
print("one")

### two.py ###
print("two")
```

to a Python class so then say I want to import `one.py`, I would be able to do:

```
importFile(MyClass.one)
```

or something like that?

Comment: You could embed code to open and import a file in a class, but to what purpose? What are you trying to do that requires that approach?

Comment: just making a library that uses some of the stuff I made. I came across bottle.py and saw it was amazing but was only in one file, so I wanted to do the same

Comment: I think your example is to simplified to correspond meaningfully to any real-word usage. If you just want one file, just make a `foo.py` file with `print("one"); print("two")` in it. No classes need to be involved in the importing, and frankly, why should they be? If you can give an example that's tied a bit more closely to reality, maybe we can answer a real question.

Comment: `def send_error(msg):    from project.error_utils import *    error_utils.send(msg)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting those statements into a class or a method and them importing the file. This is what `one.py` would look like if you wanted to make it into a method and then import it:

### one.py

```
def print_one():
    print("one")
```

### Example file with two methods (two.py)

```
def method_one():
    pass

def method_two():
    print("In method 2!")
```

### How you'd call the file (assuming you're in the same directory)

```
>>> import one
>>> one.print_one()
>>> import two
>>> two.method_one() # does nothing
>>> two.method_two()
```

You can do other more sophisticated things with Python packages by [structuring your project](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) and using things like `$PYTHONPATH` ([documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath)).

Comment: what if my files had defs in it? can you put classes/defs in defs?

Comment: Yes. when you import the file you import all of the methods, classes, variables, etc. defined in the file with certain exceptions.

Comment: this helps very much, let me try it out

Comment: Did this work for you? If it did you should mark the answer as correct to help others with the same question.

Comment: Kind of, say I use something like: `def one(): def register(): print("Registered")` and do `one() register()` register is not defined apparently

Comment: You have to put something in the body of both methods for it to register. Put `pass` in the body of a method you don't want to use.

Comment: So `def one(): pass def register(): print("Registered")`?

Comment: Understanding the code in your comments is hard because we can't tell the indentation level of each line, which makes a big difference. If you define your `register` function inside your `one` function, then the `register` function is only callable from within `one`. You can read more about namespaces [here](https://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/)