# Cannot import my module into another module

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, module, python-import

Professional Python newbie here. I have created a Python module called `aviation` with a file in there called `database.py`.

I have another module called `core`, with a file in there called `calculator.py`.

I want to import `aviation.database.py` into my `calculator.py`.

The basic structure is as follows:

```
My project
    aviation (module)
        - database.py
    core (module)
        - calculator.py
    test.py
```

My `calculator.py` file has an import such as:

```
from aviation import database as aviation_database
```

This module is not recognised and I get a red squiggly line indicating as much.

If I create another file `test.py` outside of `aviation` and `core` and add the above import, there are no issues in this `tests.py` file - the import works fine.

It appears that I need to do something so that my module can import from another module... it does allow me to import installed modules (like `date`), but I have no idea what I am missing.

I am using the IntelliJ IDE and my code is located in the regular C:\Users\\IdeaProjects directory.

Can someone tell me what I should do and why I am facing this problem?

Comment: I'd say you have to add 'My project' [pythonpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath).

Comment: @carlosvin Hmm, I have to modify system variables just to have my IDE know where the files that were created with said IDE, are? Why is it that it works from `test.py`? I'm not trying to run my code from any random location on my machine.

Comment: you don't have to modify your system variable, you can configure your IDE to add 'My project' to python path when you run the script. I am guessing you are running 'python test.py', that means that python is adding 'My project' directory to execution python path. You can try to run 'python core/calculator.py'

Comment: You might want to provide more info about your IDE and which directory are you running python from

Comment: @carlosvin Thanks, updated.

Comment: IntelliJ has a nice feature that is mark directory as source root https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html You have to do so with 'My project'

Comment: Yeah, I did find that `as source` option and I did try it, but there is no difference. Interestingly, I have found that my code does run, but IntelliJ still shows errors on imports...

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend you to create **__init__** file in the modules.

The [python3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages) states that :

> The **__init__.py** files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all**
>   variable, described later.

So your Directory Structure becomes

```
My project
    aviation (module)
        - database.py
        - __init__.py
    core (module)
        - calculator.py
        - __init__.py
    test.py
```

Now import all the thing in your **__init__** file that you want to us from other packages. Like in aviation's **__init__.py** file write

```
import database
```

Similarly, for core's **__init__.py**
Now in calculator.py you can import them by -

```
from aviation import database
```

Let me know, if this help !

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but I don't think for Python 3 we need to use __init__.py. I think it is just for packages (collections of modules). Anyway, it doesn't work.

Comment: Then a simple heck will work for you, 
append the path of your project in sys.path

Answer (score 0):

**Its as simple as this.**

For instance, you have an already written code e.g m`yname.py` and you want to import the entire module into new code e.g `newwork.py`

step 1. open your code `newwork.py`
step 2. just as you do other import, just write:

```
import myname 
myname
```

Thats all.

Now, you have your entire nyname code inside newwork. When you run newwork, it runs nymame alongside.

I hope this help somebody?