# How to select the path from which a python library is imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I have an installed python library but I want to load it from another folder without altering my installed libraries. Using the following code, I tried to replace the path to it, but now two paths are stored to load the library and the first priority is the older one. How can I set the priority to the new one (or remove the older one)?

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace('google')
pkg_resources.fixup_namespace_packages(_MY_LIBRARY_DIR)
import google.protobuf
print(google.protobuf.__path__)
```

Output: ['old path', 'new path']

Comment: Python will first look for a package in the directory of the current running program, then for a module in the same directory and then it will follow the environment variable [PYTHONPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath). Packages like virtualenv or pyenv will automate manipulation of PYTHONPATH in order to allow coexistence of several versions of the same package in the same system.

Comment: BTW this looks like a classic example of the X/Y problem. Instead of asking about your problem X (how to have conflicting versions of the same package in one system), you are asking about your devised solution Y (fiddle with the import path for Python modules).

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use `__file__` to find the path of modules and libraries,

```
print(google.protobuf.__file__)
```

but what you want to accomplish is a classic case for a virtual environment.

Virtual Environments are tools to keep the dependencies required by different projects in separate places, by creating virtual Python environments for them.

[Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

[Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

From the [Hitchhikers Guide to Python](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> A Virtual Environment is a tool to keep the dependencies required by
>   different projects in separate places, by creating virtual Python
>   environments for them. It solves the “Project X depends on version 1.x
>   but, Project Y needs 4.x” dilemma, and keeps your global site-packages
>   directory clean and manageable.