# Trying to install keyboard in command prompt "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error

Tags: python, python-module

I'm still new to python but I'm trying to get keyboard installed through the command prompt and having some difficultly. So I've added the path location but when I run it I get...

C:\Users\john>C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts pip install keyboard
'C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the path in your command and only run `pip install keyboard`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but when I run my code it say "no module named 'keyboard'" when using import keyboard.

Comment: @Midnight042 that's a separate issue. You're not running the same python interpreter that you're installing packages to. Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528638/after-pip-successful-installed-modulenotfounderror

Comment: I went back and checked the path location in environmental variables and its exactly the same file location as what I put? I don't know what I'm missing but I didn't really get anything out of that post.