# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition' - Linux

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install [speech_recognition](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/speechrecognition) on Manjaro GNU/Linux x86_64 for Python 3.8 by using the following commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge speechrecognition
```

And

```
pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
```

"conda list" command shows the following packages to be installed (amongst others):
portaudio, pyaudio, python_abi, readline, speechrecognition

However, when I try to import it:

```
import speech_recognition as st
```

It gives me the error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 import speech_recognition as st
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'

How to fix this?

Thanks

**SOLVED** with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

Comment: Did you try the answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528638/after-pip-successful-installed-modulenotfounderror ?

Comment: @Dmitry yes I have but it doesn't help