# from utils import label_map_util Import Error: No module named utils

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, import, object-detection

I am trying to run the `object_detection.ipynb` type program but it is a normal python program(.py). It is working very well but when running inside the `..models/research/object_detection` folder, but the main issue is when I am trying to run this code in another directory with proper `sys.append`, I am ending up with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "obj_detect.py", line 20, in
>
> ```
> from utils import label_map_util
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named utils

If I trying to import the file from `..models/research/object_detection` folder into a python program in a different directory, then I end up with more errors as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "classify_image.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
> import object_dt
> ```
>
> File "/home/saikishor/Tensorflow_Models/models/research/object_detection/object_dt.py", line 18, in
>
> ```
> from utils import label_map_util
> ```
>
> File "/home/saikishor/Tensorflow_Models/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 22, in
>
> ```
> from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named object_detection.protos

How to solve this issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "normal type of program"? Did you create a virtual environment for your project? Where did you get these scripts? 
Your script simply cannot see the modules you are trying to use, in other words these modules are not in Python path. You can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath

Comment: No i mean to say that I edited the code present in object_detection.ipynb to a new python file as per my requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be that your object_detection folder is not on your path, so python does not know where to look for the files.

you can check this from within python with

```
import sys

sys.path
```

if this is the problem, you can solve it by

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/object_detection')
```

Comment: The problem is you can't do that way, as the depending files inside the folder are imported in a different manner like from object_detection.ptoso import ....

Comment: what is this "path/to/your/object_detection"? i don't understand... can you explain?

Comment: The location of the object detection folder. For example "c:/projects/object_detection" or "/home/projects/object_detection"

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the same problem. that's because `string_int_label_map_pb2.py`  file doesn't exist.

1.you need to install `protobuf`.

```
https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases
```

2. `cd` your path to `object_detection`

   protoc object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map.proto --python_out=.

you will find `string_int_label_map_pb2.py` file in `'object_detection\protos'`

3. that will be ok, if there is still a problem, you can add your object_detection folder to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: You need to install protobuf 3.3, then only it works, it doesn't work with other versions

Answer (score 0):

in python*.*/site-packages folder , you can see the utils folder .
by default , when we run "from utils import label_map_util" it will try search label_map_util in python*.*/site-packages/utils folder.

this error can solve by changing the directory
or
copying a file from tensorflow/models/utils to  python*.*/site-packages/utils

Answer (score 0):

You need to download protoc version 3.3 (already compiled). Used protoc inside bin directory to run this command like this:

```
tensorflow$ mkdir protoc_3.3
tensorflow$ cd protoc_3.3
tensorflow/protoc_3.3$ wget wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
tensorflow/protoc_3.3$ chmod 775 protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
tensorflow/protoc_3.3$ unzip protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
tensorflow/protoc_3.3$ cd ../models/research/
tensorflow/protoc_3.3$ /home/saikishor/tensorflow/protoc_3.3/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

This will hopefully work!!