# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the object_detection API in Tensorflow using my webcam as an input.

The error says: "from utils import label_map_util ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'"

Which relates to the lines:

```
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

I've tried "pip install util" appears to work but doesn't solve the problem. I have also reinstalled multiple versions of protobuf as other questions online appear to have this as the solution. I don't get any errors when I install protoc so I don't think this is the issue.

I'm using python 3.6 on windows 10 with tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from utils import label\_map\_util Import Error: No module named utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494160/from-utils-import-label-map-util-import-error-no-module-named-utils)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What folder are you running your python script from?

To be able to access the 'utils' module directly, you need to be running the script inside the `<models-master>\research\object_detection` folder.

Answer (score 9):

- Instead of running script inside object detection folder append the 
  path of tensorflow object detection in your script by writing

  ```
  import sys

  sys.path.append('PATH_TO_TENSORFLOW_OBJECT_DETECTION_FOLDER')
  ```
- e.g 'PATH_TO_TENSORFLOW_OBJECT_DETECTION_FOLDER' in my ubuntu system is

  /home/dc-335/Documents/Softwares/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection
- Cheers, You done it !!

Answer (score 9):

add object_detection to the front of utils:

```
# from utils import label_map_util
# from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

Answer (score 3):

I used a quicker method to fix it.

I copied the *utils* folder from *models\research\object_detection* and pasted it within the same directory as the python file which required *utils*

Answer (score 2):

the installation didn't go through, you will notice no module called model_utils in your project folder.
uninstall it `pip uninstall django-model-utils`  then install it again `pip install django-model-utils` a new app called model_utils in your project folder.

Answer (score 2):

I used to quick method

!pip install utils

it workes properlly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

faced similar issue
download utils.py file and copy it in your project folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).