# Tensorflow API Ubuntu 14.04 python 2.7 Error

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

```
from utils import label_map_util
```

> ImportError: No module named utils

I tried to fix this problem but I can't, this similar my case
[Case 1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2482) and [Case 2](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/270)

please help me if Ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7 fix it

thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you try 'pip install utils' ?

Comment: See this:https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/ and this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494160/from-utils-import-label-map-util-import-error-no-module-named-utils

Comment: the output:Requirement already satisfied: python-utils in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from python-utils) (1.12.0)

Comment: path python 3 not python 2.7!!! how I can solve it???please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clone this:https://github.com/tensorflow/models and include the path to your code the folder  is in the research folder `research/object_detection`:

```
import sys

sys.path

sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/object_detection')
```

Or this way

```
import( os )
os.chdir( 'path/to/your/object_detection' )
```

and change your import to be:

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
```

Comment: run `sudo pip install object_detection` if you face a problem see this  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2577

Comment: thank you again, my problem in paths, it worked now 1. MODEL_NAME = '/inference_graph/placeholder.txt' , 2. CWD_PATH = os.getcwd(), 3.PATH_TO_CKPT = CWD_PATH + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb' , 4. PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','/home/redhwan/models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement object_detection (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for object_detection

Comment: thank you again, I used this link:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md, after this I change in paths (in code), finally, it worked

Comment: I am very sorry, I deleted it this comment inadvertently because of lack of experience: from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
ImportError: No module named object_detection.protos

Comment: No problem. Good luck.