# Implementing a tutorial for Tensorflow and SaaK Transform: Handwritten Digits Recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist, pytorch

I am learning to work with Tensorflow. I have installed most of the libraries.

```
# load libs
import torch
import argparse
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from data.datasets import MNIST
import torch.utils.data as data_utils
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
```

But I am facing an error like this:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-257b7af364e1> in <module>()
  5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  6 import numpy as np
----> 7 from data.datasets import MNIST
  8 import torch.utils.data as data_utils
  9 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

ImportError: No module named data.datasets
```

I have installed the "dataset" library using the following command:

```
sudo -H pip install dataset
```

But I am still seeing this error. I am using python 2.7.
I am pretty new to python. Can anyone help me in identifying the missing thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you point out the tutorial you are following?

Comment: @Mehraban Sure. This is the tutorial I am following:
https://github.com/davidsonic/Saak-Transform/blob/master/main.py

Comment: you need to add PATH-TO/Saak-Transform into PYTHONPATH or PATH. This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath. To learn python before you work on Tensorflow.

Comment: @caot Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. So where should this tree be made, inside main.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataset` directory is placed next to `main.py`, so probably when you tried `sudo -H pip install dataset` you actually installed a irrelevant package.

So uninstall the wrong package and it would work:

```
sudo -H pip uninstall dataset
```