# Run python script in package

Tags: python

I am struggling with running python script in shell. I use PyCharm where is everything ok, but I want to run script without running PyCharm.

So my project folder is like:

- `data/`

  - `file.txt`
- `main/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `script.py`
- `tools/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `my_strings.py`

I want to run `main/script.py`, which start with `from tools import my_strings` and working directory should be `data/`.

My PyCharm config is:

- Script path: `<PROJECT>/main/script.py`
- Working directory: `<PROJECT>/data`
- Add content roots to PYTHONPATH: YES
- Add source roots to PYTHONPATH: YES

So I want to run `main/script.py` in shell on Ubuntu. I tried:

```
PYTHONPATH=<PROJECT>
cd <PROJECT>/data
python3 ../main/script.py
```

But I just got: `ImportError: No module named 'tools'`

Comment: How is your import statement look like in `script.py`?

Comment: Try running it from the top level project folder.

Comment: @Rafael I wrote it in question: `from tools import my_strings`

Comment: You need to set the python path yourself since pycharm isn't doing it for you

Comment: @PierreOcinom It does not work also. And I need `data/` as working directory, because it uses `open('file.txt')`.

Comment: @Steve I am trying it with `PYTHONPATH=/my/project/path`. Isn't it enough?

Comment: did you export it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post, it's explains the PYTHONPATH variable.

[How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath) and the documentation the answer points to https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

When you run from the data directory by default python can't find your tools directory.

Also regarding your comment about needing to run from the data directory, you could just use `open('../data/file.txt')` if you decided to run from the main directory instead.

Ideally, you should be able to run your script from anywhere though. I find this snippet very useful `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`. It returns the directory in which the script exists.

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to `export $PYTHONPATH` as suggested by Steve.