# Importing local module (python script) in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to import a local module (a python script) to my DAG.

Directory structure:

```
airflow/
├── dag
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_DAG.py
└── script
    └── subfolder
        ├── __init__.py
        └── local_module.py
```

Sample code in my_DAG.py:

```
#trying to import from local module
from script.subfolder import local_module  

#calling a function in local_module.py  
a = some_function()
```

I get an error in Airflow saying 'Broken DAG: my_DAG. No module named 'local_module'.

I've updated Airflow to 1.9.0 but this doesn't fix the issue.

- What is the solution here?
- I also read somewhere that I could solve this by creating a plugin. Can anyone point to how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This usually has to do with how Airflow is configured.

In `airflow.cfg`, make sure the path in `airflow_home` is correctly set to the path the Airflow directory strucure is in.

Then Airflow scans all subfolders and populates them so that modules can be found.

Otherwise, just make sure the folder you are trying to import is in the Python path: [How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath)

Comment: My `airflow.cfg` _has_ no `airflow_home`. Has this changed since this answer was posted?

Comment: You can also achieve this by setting `export AIRFLOW_HOME=path_to_my_airflow_home_dir` .

Comment: would appreciate links to docs, especially since these answers can get stale as the versions go up

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#additional-modules-in-airflow according to the link Airflow only adds "dag", "plugins" and "config" to "sys.path",  "airflow_home" will not be in the path

Answer (score 4):

The way I do it is as following:

1. create a Python script in your sub-folder with a main() function.
2. in your dag file include a path declaration for the sub-folder and the file

Now you can use this script in your `PythonOperator`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/root/airflow/dags/subfolder"))
import subfolder.script_name as script
...    
t1=PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_script',
    python_callable=script.main,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: lets say file is under dags/script/file1.py, how do I import it?

Answer (score 4):

**If you run Airlow in a docker** then you need to do it as following:

1. Create a folder for your modules in dags folder. For example
   *programs*
2. Use it as following (this is the correct path for docker):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/airflow/dags/programs/my_module')
import my_module
task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='my_task_name',
        python_callable=my_module.my_func,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Comment: i test following code and t works for me with some changes:
i changed " sys.path.append('/opt/airflow/dags/programs/my_module') " to
" sys.path.append('/opt/airflow/dags/programs/') "
it seems there is no need to add python filename at the end of path

Comment: not very nice but works, instead of path I use: `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`