# Python refer to module with partial path

Tags: python, python-import

I have this directory structure:

```
├── package1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── package2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module2.py
└── script.py
```

The script.py file looks like this:

```
import package1.package2.module2
import package1.package2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    package1.package2.module2.run()  # This works
    package2.module2.run()           # This fails
```

Execution fails with this error, NameError: name 'package2' is not defined.

How can I change the code in such a way that `package2.module2` is recognized as an imported module?

Comment: have you tried using the leading dot notation from the docs? I don't see why what you have laid out wouldn't work. what's the error? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: Updated the question with the error message NameError: name 'package2' is not defined.

Comment: @Steve : It seems that there is no `package2` directory with a `module2` file in it.  That may be the reason of the error.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj Understood.  The reason for the original question is to enhance readability with a partial path, without becoming too verbose with the full path.

Comment: @Steve : So we can assume it exists at that location, right?

Comment: This SO post may help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810656/python-folder-structure-for-project-directory-and-easy-import) It seems like there may be submodule conventions that you're deviating from (see Michael liv. answer)

Comment: @wim yes, that works.  Make this an answer and I will mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `script.py` is bugged for expecting the `package2` name to just appear out of nowhere - the import statements shown only bring the name `package1` into the namespace.

It could use `from package1 import package2` instead, so that `package2` is in the namespace. In this case, importing the `module2` separately is [still required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49641621/674039).

Most typical would be a single import statement:

```
from package1.package2.module2 import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Yes it works, but you're right -- I need to import both the package and the module when using the partial path notation.