# Python import module issue on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have two python files :

`DatabaseFunctions.py` and `tele_bot.py` .

On windows side  I'm importing `DatabaseFunctions.py` module inside `tele_bot.py` and everything is fine .

import code line : `from .DatabaseFunctions import *`

when I upload my files in `ubuntu` server side , I'm getting this error :

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I also tried `from appname.DatabaseFunction import *` then I got this :

```
No module named 'appname'
```

Here is my directory structure :

```
firstBot/
      __init__.py
      DatabaseFunctions.py
      tele_bot.py
```

anyone can help ?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in the imported module directory? Is the path correct?

Comment: @ggdx yeah i have __init__.py  and checked the paths .

Comment: Can you please add your directory structure to your question?

Comment: @toti08 please check edited question

Comment: Did you try removing the `.` from the line `from .DatabaseFunctions import *`?

Comment: @toti08 Unresolved reference 'DatabaseFunctions'

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use

```
import firstBot.DatabaseFunctions
```

This should work on windows or linux. But i would recommend to use lowercase file- and foldernames like  `firstbot/database_functions.py`, so it may look like that:

```
from firstbot.database_functions import *
```

Comment: this will raise this error : ' ImportError: No module named 'firstBot' '

Comment: Do you have the parent directory in your `$PYTHONPATH` variable?

Comment: @norok2 Can you please explain more about this variable ?

Comment: @Mehdibmp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath#19917565

Comment: @norok2 ok thanks , where can i find this variable and add my directory ?

Comment: @Mehdibmp something like `sys.path.append(<my dir>)` should do the trick.