# Python package/module import

Tags: python

I've gone through a lot of resources, but I simply cannot get this to work.
I am trying to do an absolute import for some config files and library class files of my own, but the import fails.
Here is a simple example:

```
└── import_test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── config
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── database.py
    └── services
        ├── __init__.py
        └── data.py
```

Here is the database.py

```
mysql = {'host':    'localhost',
         'user':    'root',
         'passwd':  'password',
         'db':      'db_name',
         'charset': 'utf8'}
```

and here is data.py

```
from import_test.config import database
```

When I run the data.py, I get this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_test'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The Python interpreter's working directory and the setting of PYTHONPATH in the environment will make a difference here (as will, possibly, other more esoteric settings).  Please update your question to include this information.  Thanks!

Comment: Put it another way, print out `sys.path` before the error, and figure out if it contains the parent of `import_test`. If not, make it so.

Comment: So, this worked:  
  
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/test/import_test")  
  
But does that mean, I have to do this in every page that's burried inside subfolders?
What if I have to move files and change the structure?
I thought the point of absolute import was that you have more freedome to move things around...

Sorry, I tried to format the code section, but I don't know how...

Comment: PYTHONPATH worked beautifully!
I've created a simple shell script to add the top of the project to the PYTHONPATH and now I am calling the shell script file in the cron instead of directly calling the python file.
This is the way, right?
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your top working directory to PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: So, this worked: 

    import sys  
    sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/test/import_test")  

But does that mean, I have to do this in every page that's burried inside subfolders? What if I have to move files and change the structure? I thought the point of absolute import was that you have more freedome to move things around... Sorry, I tried to format the code section, but I don't know how...

Comment: Here is good explanation about PYTHONPATH and how does it work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath

Also you can create virtual environment and add needed path to PYTHONPATH permanently in activation file

Comment: It worked beautifully!
I've created a simple shell script to add the top of the project to the PYTHONPATH and now I am calling the shell script file in the cron instead of directly calling the python file.
This is the way, right?
Thanks a bunch!