# Shebang doesn't have the same import available?

Tags: python, pandas

In Linux, if I type in
`which python2.7` I get `/usr/bin/python2.7`. If I type in `/usr/bin/python2.7` to bring up the Python2.7 environment, and I type in `import pandas as pd` it works fine.

Now I'm running a python file on apache2 on the same server with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`
next line I put `import pandas as pd` and the error log spits out `No module named pandas`. I don't understand why it doesn't work if it's using the same Python?

Also Here's if I do `python2.7 -m site`

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/archie',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/archie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.21.0-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simple_salesforce-0.74.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
]
```

if I do `pip2.7 uninstall pandas`
I get

```
Uninstalling pandas-0.23.4:
  Would remove:
    /home/archie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.23.4.dist-info/*
    /home/archie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/*
```

Comment: For example, it could be that `$PYTHONPATH` is different between your account and the account that Apache is running under. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath

Comment: `apache2` is it a different server ? username ?

Comment: @NPE It's under the same server, same user

Comment: @GaurangShah It's under the same server, same user. I'm pretty sure

Comment: have you tried the shebang line #!/usr/bin/env python   ?

Comment: @user2660966 Already tried env, same result

Comment: Daemons don't run `.bashrc` or `.profile`, which may be setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: so are you running with apache user or not ? if so `'/home/archie/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',` this might create an issue, make sure apache user has access to this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bash-like shell you might also want to try typing `type python2.7`.  It's entirely possible there's an alias, which `which` is completely unaware of.