# Running python from command line, only project imports are failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to run my python code from command line instead of from my IDE. I have cloned my project from git, and made a python 3 virtual env. I have activated my venv and commands like `python --version` correctly print the python version in my venv (as apposed to the version I would get running the same command outside the venv, which is different in my case) so I know I am using venv right. Once in the activated venv, I pip install my 3rd party packages from a requirments.txt file with pip `pip install -r requirements.txt` but I am still having trouble running my code. Here is my directory layout:

```
project_folder
├── env_vars
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── env_vars.py
|
├── tests
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── test.py
|
└── __init__.py
```

and I am trying to run test.py which has imports that look like:

```
import os  # python built in, gets past this line no problem
from 3rd_praty_lib import 3rd_party_thing  # this is a library I installed with pip, again gets past this line no problem
from env_vars import env_vars  # <- this is where the failure happens. referencing my own code
```

So basically my issue is:

when in the tests directory I use the command `python test.py` and I get this error:

```
 File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from env_vars import env_vars
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env_vars'
```

Comment: did you add the library path to the pythonpath?

Comment: whats is pythonpath?

Comment: yeah, that is your problem => https://stackoverflow.com/a/19917565/1695172

Comment: just a quick guess: From env_vars.env_vars import env_vars

Comment: Just add this before your imports: `import sys; sys.path.append('..')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should had your package to the python path

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

Comment: This whole time I thought "python path" was just referring to the "path" env var, and not an env var literally called "python path"