# cannot import module from a folder

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I'm using VSCODE as my editor and using Python 3.7
I have this kind of folder structure

```
project
|-- util
   | -- drivers.py
   | -- data.py
   | -- __init__.py
|-- test
   | -- driver_test.py
   | -- __init__.py
main.py
```

I want to import `drivers.py` from util folder into `driver_test.py`
I tried to do basic import like this

```
from util.drivers import Driver
```

which didn't work since it couldn't find `util` module, then I used another approach by adding a folder to `sys.path`.  like this

```
# driver_test.py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('./util'))
import drivers
```

I got very confused with several output errors.
When I run my unittest from console I'm getting error that drivers are not found

```
import drivers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drivers'
```

And if i run test file in vscode editor by right click and `Run current test file`, the error output is different that selenium driver is not found which is included inside `drivers.py` file

```
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Selenium module is actually working fine and I just wanted to right several unittest for it and most. What I'm doing wrong and how can this be solved? 
And is it possible to include a module without using `sys.path` just by using import.

Comment: How are you running your code? And which version of python?

Comment: You might need to set PYTHONPATH as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath).

Comment: @Alexander adding `__init__.py` to test folder didn't help, and i''m running my tests from vscode by right click and as well tried via console

Comment: If you want to modify `sys.path`, you don't add packages to it, but _directories that contain packages_ instead. In your case, I think `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))`will already do, but it's more robust to calculate the path relative to the `__file__` attribute. For example, `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir)))` - this way the path won't change if you e.g. run the tests from another directory etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set your PYTHONPATH, to the `project` directory. More on that in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath) on the StackOverflow forums or on the [official Python website](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

Comment: i'm wondering why did `sys.path` didn't work and keep showing an error with selenium module not found

Comment: @Andrew it is quite possible that VSCode is using a different Python Interpreter, with different modules installed in its directory. Open the Command Pallet (Ctrl + Shift + P) and select "Python: Select Interpreter". Check that it's the version of Python you're looking for. As a worst case scenario, reinstall the module via PIP, in regards to the Selenium related error.