# What's the point of adding a program to PATH?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm done with installing Pycharm, and throughout the wizard, there was a tickbox saying: add to PATH (restart required).

What extra benefit would I get from ticking that box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath)

Comment: As with adding any executable's location to your path (or vice versa), you'd be able to invoke it by name alone, without providing the full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very short answer, somebody can provide details also I am not an expert.

If in windows, adding to path is like adding the program to the environment variables. This means, that instead of executing it to the full path where the .exe is you could call it with an "alias".

To run python, instead of going somewhere like C:/Program Files/Python/python.exe you could simply type "python".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think PyCharm will want you to put itself in PATH (aside from the `charm` helper maybe, which launches the IDE akin to `subl` or `code` for Sublime Text and Visual Studio Code respectively).

Having Python in `PATH` (I recall the installer does ask that on Windows) will make it possible for you to run `python`, `pip` and the other tools from any directory when using the command line.