# PyPy not finding packages

Tags: python, macos, pypy

I'm relatively new to coding, this is my first Stack Overflow question! I recently installed PyPy. It works fine if the code I'm running doesn't import much. But when my code tries to import, e.g., NumPy, I get: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'." Same with other major packages; though it seems to import Itertools. I know I have all these packages somewhere, because they work when I run the code through Jupyter, etc. Googling around it seems like PyPy should support all the major packages, so I assume I need to link them up somehow...? Any advice or links to resources much appreciated!

MacOS 10.15.1

```
$ pypy3 --version
Python 3.6.9 (5da45ced70e515f94686be0df47c59abd1348ebc, Nov 22 2019, 03:55:25)
[PyPy 7.2.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install the packages? Did you do `pip install` or `pypy3 -mpip install`? The latter is what you should use if you have more than one Python installed so that they are installed for your desired Python and not the system default.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to this, sorry for my boneheadednessm really appreciate your help. I installed Anaconda to begin with, and have since pip installed a few things. I checked a few, and looks like they all live in the same place: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Comment: I did what Nate below said and added the following to .zprofile

PYTHONPATH="/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH

Now it appears to know where to look, but I think PyPy is not compatible with the latest Python version I have located here. Now I get a new ImportError:

Check that you expected to use Python3.6 from "/usr/local/bin/pypy3",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

try use same python executable with jupyter.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

or install packages with `pip install numpy`

if you can find the install location for your package with somthing like

```py
import numpy
print(numpy.__file__)
```

add the site-package folder to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable should work for you.

see [How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath)

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I added to PYTHONPATH successfully, but got a new error, perhaps because pypy3 isn't compatible with the latest pypi packages...? Reading through some documentation, I think maybe I need to install a virtual environment and run pypy3 out of that...? Does that sound reasonable, any idea of good references to walk through how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: @dan-brendel i never used anaconda and pypy, but i guess you are not running the [anaconda python executable](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/)?